# Intrinsic type vs. primitive non-intrinsic type

Tags: types, fortran, primitive, primitive-types

I've come across the word 'intrinsic type' in fortran which I've never heard before:

> Fortran has five intrinsic data types: integer, real, complex, logical, and character.

Is intrinsic the same thing as "primitive", or is there a slight difference in meaning? What is the opposite of an intrinsic type (I would imagine something like a date or decimal): what would that be called?

Comment: What do you mean by "primitive"?  ('Intrinsic' is defined by Fortran but 'primitive' isn't.  We can tell you the first but need to know what to compare with.

Comment: Primitive might be what other languages call that's intrinsic in Fortran. But primitive is not a thing in Fortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran Standard defines *intrinsic* (generally, not only for type) as:

> 1.3.93
>
> **intrinsic**
>
> type, procedure, module, assignment, operator, or input/output operation defined in this part of ISO/IEC 153917 and accessible without further definition or specification, or a procedure or module provided by a processor but not defined in this part of ISO/IEC 1539.

Moreover, it defines intrinsic type as follow:

> 1.3.147.8
>
> **intrinsic type**
>
> type defined by this part of ISO/IEC 1539 that is always accessible.

So the main difference between an intrinsic type and a derived type is that you *must* import a library in order to use the last one. (I have previously made an example of a *non-intrinsic* using real(real64) from `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` library, but as francescalus pointed out in the comments, it is not the case.)

You may also want to check session 4.4 of the Standard, which specifically deals with intrinsic types in detail. The Fortran Standard [copy I have](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) is unofficial and not the latest one, but the most recent ones are compliant with the old ones as part of Fortran philosophy.

I have not find any match for `primitive` in the Fortran Standard, so I believe this nomenclature is not used in Fortran. I've also checked C standard and could not really find anything official, but every definition I find for the term in other languages - for instance in Java - basically defines it as a type which comes with the language, i.e, intrinsic. :)

Perhaps the difference you are looking for is that although `real` is an intrinsic type in Fortran, `double precision` is not:

> The type specifier for the real type uses the keyword REAL. The keyword DOUBLE PRECISION is an alternative specifier for one kind of real type. If the type keyword REAL is used without a kind type parameter, the real type with default real kind is specified and  the  kind  value  is  KIND  (0.0).   The  type  specifier  DOUBLE  PRECISION  specifies  type  real  with  double precision kind; the kind value is KIND (0.0D0).  The decimal precision of the double precision real approximation method shall be greater than that of the default real method.

However, in other languages, types such as `short` and `long` may be understood as different primitives.

Comment: By a "real_64 type" do you mean something like `real(real64)`. I assume you do, because of the mention of `iso_fortran_env`.  `real(real64)` is intrinsic: it's a real intrinsic type and the kind parameter is just a constant which could just as well be `350`.

Comment: `double precision` denotes an intrinsic type: a real.

Comment: That is a pretty interesting observation about `real64`. I haven't realized that it was just a constant.

Comment: I believe I haven't made my point with the `double precision` clear. I'm saying that `double precision` is a variation (kind) of `real` but it doesn't constitute a different intrinsic itself, it is still a real, as you pointed. However, in other languages, a *double*, a *short* and a *long*, for instance, may be documented as different primitives instead of kinds of the same primitive.

Answer (score 2):

An intrinsic type is one of those data types that is both defined by the Fortran standard and is always accessible (the answer by rvbarreto contains an explicit definition quote).  As of Fortran 2018 those are the five of the question.

Before Fortran 90's introduction of the kind-parameter system there was the type `double precision` but this is not now a different intrinsic type: it refers to the intrinsic type `real` with a specific kind parameter.

Distinct to an intrinsic type would be something similar: a type which is always accessible but defined by a particular processor (compiler) instead.  One example could be a `byte` data type.

Further, there are *derived data types*.  These are not intrinsic and can be both defined by the user or by a processor.  A derived type such as `c_ptr` may be defined by the Fortran standard but, because it is defined in the intrinsic module `iso_c_binding`, it is not always accessible: it is not an intrinsic type.

A derived data type defined by the user could look something like:

```
type :: date
   real :: seconds_since_epoch
end type date

type :: decimal(digits)
   integer, kind :: digits
   integer :: value(digits)
end type decimal
```

These would not be always accessible (being defined by the user) and are not defined by the standard.

---

The term *nonintrinsic* is defined by the standard, but this doesn't apply to data types (simply modules and procedures).  There's no defined term for "data types which are not intrinsic".  We could use *derived type* or *non-standard type* depending on which case above we want to catch.  With "primitive" one may be more inclined to take a non-standard processor-defined data type.

Consider:

```
real a ! Intrinsic
byte b ! Non-standard 'primitive' perhaps (if supported)
type(byte) c ! Derived type, non-standard/user
type(c_ptr) d ! Standard (if referring to that of iso_c_binding)
type(real) e ! Intrinsic!
double precision f ! Intrinsic (real)
```